# Extracting values of list inputs in R Shiny Server.R function

Tags: r, list, input, shiny

I have the following input variables:

1. no_of_structures
2. no_of_legs_in_structure

I have defined the input variable no_of_structures in the ui.R function
I have then defined the variable no_of_legs_in_structure in the server.R function.
I am trying to extract the "values" entered by the user for each "no_of_legs_in_structure" through the below code (output$test3) and am failing.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    
  
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      
      #Enter Number of Structures to Analyse
      numericInput(inputId = "number_of_structures",
                   label = "enter number of structures",
                   value = 1,
                   min = 1,
                   max = Inf,
                   step=1),
      
  
      uiOutput("test2")
    

    ),# closing bracket for sidebarPanel
    
    
    mainPanel(
    
  textOutput("test1"), 
  uiOutput("test3")
  
  
    )#closing for mainPanel
    
    
    
  )#closing bracket for sidebarLayout
)#closing bracket for fluidPage




############ Below is code for server

server <- function(input, output){
  
#printing the number of structures entered by user

  
output$test1 <- renderText(paste0("number of structures entered by user are:- ", input$number_of_structures))
  
  
# Enter number of legs for each structure
  

  

 no_of_legs_in_structure <- reactive({
   lapply(1:input$number_of_structures, function(k){#start of function
    numericInput(inputId= "no_of_legs_in_structure",
                 label = paste0("no_of_legs_in_structure",k),
                 value=1,
                 min=0,
                 max=6,
                 step=1)
  })#end of lapply function and lapply

 })

  
  output$test2 <- renderUI(no_of_legs_in_structure())
  
 
  
  
  
  
  #Trying to extract number of legs in each structure
  
output$test3 <- 
  
 renderUI( 
    lapply(1:input$number_of_structures, function(k){
    (paste0("number of legs in Str::",k, "are",input$no_of_legs_in_structure[k], "\n" ))
  
  })


)
 
 
 
 
}# ending bracket for server function



shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what i am doing wrong in the code snippet where i am rendering the output for test3.  I am trying to extract the values which the user inputs in the fields for "no_of_legs_in_structure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your step generating the `no_of_legs_in_structure` UI elements is wrong. With the `lapply`, you've created `k` inputs all with the same `id`. I've added `k` to the id so that you can distinguish the inputs. However, I don't like generating UI elements with `lapply` and `renderUI`, have a look at `insertuI` and `removeUI` for a cleaner approach.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    
    
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      
      #Enter Number of Structures to Analyse
      numericInput(inputId = "number_of_structures",
                   label = "enter number of structures",
                   value = 1,
                   min = 1,
                   max = Inf,
                   step=1),
      
      
      uiOutput("test2")
      
      
    ),# closing bracket for sidebarPanel
    
    
    mainPanel(
      
      textOutput("test1"), 
      uiOutput("test3")
      
      
    )#closing for mainPanel
    
    
    
  )#closing bracket for sidebarLayout
)#closing bracket for fluidPage




############ Below is code for server

server <- function(input, output){
  
  #printing the number of structures entered by user
  
  
  output$test1 <- renderText(paste0("number of structures entered by user are:- ", input$number_of_structures))
  
  
  # Enter number of legs for each structure
  
  
  
  
  no_of_legs_in_structure <- reactive({
    lapply(1:input$number_of_structures, function(k){#start of function
      numericInput(inputId= paste0("no_of_legs_in_structure_", k),
                   label = paste0("no_of_legs_in_structure",k),
                   value=1,
                   min=0,
                   max=6,
                   step=1)
    })#end of lapply function and lapply
    
  })
  
  
  output$test2 <- renderUI(no_of_legs_in_structure())
  
  
  
  
  
  
  #Trying to extract number of legs in each structure
  
  output$test3 <- 
    
    renderUI( 
      lapply(1:input$number_of_structures, function(k){
        (paste0("number of legs in Str::",k, "are",input[[paste0("no_of_legs_in_structure_", k)]], "\n" ))
        
      })
      
      
    )
  
  
  
  
}# ending bracket for server function



shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```